# Getting number of a clicked div - and out of dynamic written group of divs - in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a html like shown bellow. What im trying to achieve is, after I click on a specific div, to get clean number out of that div(id) as a var in a jQuery. Just a number.

PHP is writing html like this.. ability to delete via label id jquery code is even more welcome (so ie. level does not need to be numerated). :s

```
<div id="level_1">aaa
  <label id="del_1">Delete this post</label>
</div>

<div id="level_2">bbb
  <label id="del_2">Delete this post</label>
</div>
```

Something like level_1 (or del_1) to become var num = 1, level_2 (or del_2) to become var num = 2; and so on. You are free to change this html also to obey jQuery if necessary, or just to be more clean. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$('[id^="level_"],[id^="del_"]').click(function() {
   var num = (this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [])[0];
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkur5/).

This selects elements of which their `id` attribute starts with either `level_` or `del_`.

It then extracts the trailing digits on the `id` attribute once clicked.

If it could not find any trailing digits, `num` will be `undefined`.
    ​

Comment: yes it does it..thx! do you know how to do it without trailing digits since it is not necessary.. just with del_ id?

Comment: @Joseph I'm not 100% sure what you mean. If it is not trailing digits, replace the `\d+` with `_(.+)` and change the capturing group subscript from `0` to `1`.

Comment: Yeah my mistake I had few more label ids in a file so that messed me up. It does perfect, thanx Alex.